# Duplicate Record (Error 1062)

Tags: php

Good morning everyone. May I ask what's wrong with this code? I already tried every solution here at stackoverflow about the duplicate entry but nothing worked. Here's the code..

```
public function do_add_menu_accounts($chkmenus,$chknamedivsect) {

        $sql_check = "SELECT
                      fsiportaldb2.tbl_user_access.account_id,
                      fsiportaldb2.tbl_user_access.menu_id,
                      fsiportaldb2.tbl_accounts.account_id AS account_id1
                    FROM
                      fsiportaldb2.tbl_user_access
                      INNER JOIN fsiportaldb2.tbl_accounts ON fsiportaldb2.tbl_accounts.account_id = fsiportaldb2.tbl_user_access.account_id"
                      ;

        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_user_access (`menu_id`,`account_id`) VALUES (?,?)";   
        $data = array($chkmenus, $chknamedivsect);

        $query_1 = $this->db->query($sql_check,$data);
        $query = $this->db->query($sql,$data);

        if ($query_1) 
        {
            echo "Values already exist!";       
        }else{
            return $query;
        }                                                               
}
```

Comment: You execute the `insert` regardless of the `select` results.

Comment: How is `do_add_menu_accounts()` called? Are you definitely passing the parameters into the function? It may pay to validate those.

Comment: Yes, I'm passing the parameters from user input to the function.

Comment: Yes, that's why I want to have an error message that will prompt the user that he already inserted that data instead of duplicate error that the browser gives to user. My first query is for selecting if there is already same existing entry and the second one is for inserting if there is no same entry that exists.

Comment: Why you need to use inner join? why directly check in the tbl_user_access, you're basis was the account_id

Comment: $sql_check="SELECT tbl_user_access WHERE `account_id`='?";